# NSolid Sass Getting 404 page

Tags: nsolid

When i start my npm process and following instruction to open nsolid console on sass
i'm getting 404 page

https://my-token.saas.nodesource.io

In console N|Solid warning:  Unable to connect to the Bulk remote on tcp://token.proxy.saas.nodesource.io:30294, please verify address!  Continuing to try...